# getDeviceLocation() method update current position marker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have followed official documentation to display google maps and track user location.
Right now thanks to  `googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`line i can display a blue dot on map which is updating based on user location.What i am trying to do is instead of this default blue dot i would like to display a custom marker.

```
public   class tab2_fragment extends Fragment  {
    private static final String TAG = "Tab2Fragment";
    MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private Location mLastKnownLocation;
    private final LatLng mDefaultLocation = new LatLng(-33.8523341, 151.2106085);
    private boolean zoomed = false;
    private boolean firstPass = true;

    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
    private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted;

    PlaceDetectionClient mPlaceDetectionClient;
    FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2_fragment, container, false);
        final Context context = getActivity();

        getLocationPermission();
        // Construct a PlaceDetectionClient.
        mPlaceDetectionClient = Places.getPlaceDetectionClient(context, null);

        // Construct a FusedLocationProviderClient.
        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);


        mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately
        // googleMap.setMapStyle(
        // MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
        //this, R.raw.mapstyle));
        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                googleMap = mMap;

                // Turn on the My Location layer and the related control on the map.
                updateLocationUI();

                getDeviceLocation();

                // Get the current location of the device and set the position of the map.


                //googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            }


        });

        return rootView;
    }


    private void getLocationPermission() {

        Context context = getActivity();

        /*
     * Request location permission, so that we can get the location of the
     * device. The result of the permission request is handled by a callback,
     * onRequestPermissionsResult.
     */
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this.getActivity(),
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String permissions[],
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                }
            }
        }
        updateLocationUI();
    }

    private void updateLocationUI() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


                googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            } else {
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                mLastKnownLocation = null;
                getLocationPermission();
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void getDeviceLocation() {
        /*
         * Get the best and most recent location of the device, which may be null in rare
         * cases when a location is not available.
         */
        try {
            if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
                Task<Location> locationResult = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Set the map's camera position to the current location of the device.
                            mLastKnownLocation = task.getResult();

                            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                    new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                                            mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), 20));
                            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()))
                                    .title("Current Location"));


                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Current location is null. Using defaults.");
                            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: %s", task.getException());

                            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
        }
    }


}
```

I have question about getDeviceLocation method.Is it called everytime when users location changed ? I put this lines to try but seems like its not updating position of marker.

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()))
                                    .title("Current Location"));
```

Comment: private static final LatLng YOURLOCATION= new LatLng(-37.813, 144.962);
  private Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(YOURLOCATION)
                            .title("Melbourne")
                            .snippet("Population: 4,137,400")
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow)));

please use this to add custom icon on map

Answer (score 0):

No,Its not called every time when user location change, for that you need to use **onLocationChanged(Location location)** that's called when the **location has changed**. for better understanding please see this [LINK](https://www.journaldev.com/13325/android-location-api-tracking-gps)